# Postfix Notation Calculator (RPN) Problems C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, postfix-notation, rpn

Hate coming back for help after getting help on the same program just a few days ago, but I am really struggling to finish this program.  In short, I need to create a postfix notation calculator (RPN) with a linked list stack, that allows me to do expressions such as 5 5 5 + + (=15).  I've managed to get the main calculation part down now, but I am struggling with handling two of the errors.  One of which is "too many operators," and the other, "too many operands."  Currently working on "too many operators" and I feel like I am close but can't quite get there.

If the user enters 5 5 + + on the first entry, it catches it and says "too many operands." However, if something is already in the stack from a previous calculation, and they then type the same expression 5 5 + +, it is not saying that the stack is empty, and is instead outputting an answer with the previous number being used.  If anyone can see where I am going wrong here, and also point me in a direction for figuring out the other error "too many operators" (ex: 5 5 5 +) that'd be greatly appreciated.  Thanks again in advance.

(After messing with it more, it seems the more calculations I do, the more operators actually need to be put in place to be considered empty.  I'm guessing I need to popVal somewhere before each expression but not sure where to put it, as I've tried many places and it's not working)

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

class SLLNode
{
    double data;
    SLLNode *top;
    SLLNode *ptr;
public:
    SLLNode()
    {
        top = NULL;
        ptr =  NULL;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return top == 0;
    }

    void pushVal(double val)
    {
        SLLNode *next = new SLLNode;
        next -> data = val;
        next -> ptr = top;
        top = next;
    }

    double popVal()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            cout << "Error: Too many operators" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
        SLLNode *next = top -> ptr;
        double ret = top -> data;
        delete top;
        top = next;
        return ret;
        }

    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << top -> data << endl;
    }
};


bool isOperator(const string& input)
{
    string ops[] = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(input == ops[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


void performOp(const string& input, SLLNode& stack)
{
    double fVal, sVal;
    int errorCheck = 0;

    sVal = stack.popVal();
    fVal = stack.popVal();

    if(input == "+")
    {
        stack.pushVal(fVal + sVal);
    }
    else if(input == "-")
    {
        stack.pushVal(fVal - sVal);
    }
    else if(input == "*")
    {
        stack.pushVal(fVal * sVal);
    }
    else if(input == "/" && sVal != 0)
    {
        stack.pushVal(fVal / sVal);
    }


    if(input == "/" && sVal == 0)
    {
        cout << "Error: Division by zero" << endl;
        errorCheck = 1;
    }

    if(errorCheck == 0)
    {
    stack.print();
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "::::::::::::::::RPN CALCULATOR:::::::::::::::::" << endl;
    cout << "::TYPE IN A POSTFIX EXPRESSION OR 'q' TO QUIT::" << endl;
    cout << ":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::" << endl << endl;

    string input;
    SLLNode stack;
    while(true)
    {
        cin >> input;
        double num;

        if(istringstream(input) >> num)
        {
            stack.pushVal(num);
        }
        else if (isOperator(input))
        {
            performOp(input, stack);
        }
        else if (input == "q")
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "if something is already in the stack from a previous calculation, and they then type the same expression `5 5 + +`, it is not saying that the stack is empty, and is instead outputting an answer with the previous number being used." Why is that a problem? If you type in `2`, and then `5 5 + +`, don't you want `12` to be printed?

Comment: Similarly with `5 5 5 +`: why is this a problem? What if I want to eventually enter `5 5 5 + +` - why do you want to prevent me from doing that?

Comment: I just want each line to be it's own expression.  And if someone types in an expression 5 5 5 + it has to output "too many operators."  Sorry, not exactly sure what you guys are asking as I am kind of new to this.  It should only ready (x) amount of operators and (x-1) amount of operands, if this isn't the case then I need to print an error.  If someone types in 2 only, and hits enter, then enter 5 5 + +, i still want it to say too many operands.  If someone types in 2, enter, then 5 5 +, I want it to say 10.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to:

1. Read one line ([std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline));
2. Process this line ([std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream));
3. Output the answer or any errors;
4. Clean the stack (or destroy it and create a new one on step 2);
5. Go to 1 and repeat.

What you are missing is the first step. If you get everything directly from stdin, you will treat the newline as a simple whitespace.